# Python 3.4 Compiler?

Tags: python

Ever since I started learning Python, I have wanted to distribute some small programs I have made to my friends. Without handing out my source code. My question is, what compilers are there for Python 3.4? I have heard of cx_freeze and tried it, but it doesn't work for me. I am on Windows and it compiles my code for Mac. Any compiler suggestions or how to compile?

PLEASE NOTE: I am a beginner to Python. I barely know much of the language or how any of it works.

Comment: First, Python already has a compiler built in; it's the thing that (among other things) makes `.pyc` files out of your `.py` files. If you just want to distribute .pyc files instead of .py files for everything (except one top-level wrapper script), that just works out of the box.

Comment: Next, `cx_Freeze` isn't a compiler; it's a program that packages together a Python application. There are alternatives to that (`pyInstaller`, `py2app` on Mac, `py2exe` on Windows, etc.), and various other ways to distribute packaged-up applications, but none of them compile anything. And if you're looking for recommendations on a particular one, Stack Overflow isn't a good site for software recommendations; try [Software Recs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), or a non-Q&A site like a forum or a mailing list.

Comment: Finally, what are you really after here? Are you just trying to hide your source? If so, why? And how well do you want it hidden? How clever are your friends? Python compiled bytecode is pretty high-level, and not hard to decompile back to source code. You can run an obfuscator that renames all your names to things like `a123` and scrambles all the line numbers and even adds intentionally misleading code, all of which makes it a little harder to read, but anyone who knows anything about reverse engineering is still going to figure out what your code does.

Comment: I suggest that you edit your original question to reflect the fact that you just want to create an installer that installs all the python perquisites that your Python scripts need.  I'm sure that you got down voted so many times because you're new to Python and used the term "compiler" in appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this page.  It should answer your question.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/DistributionUtilities

INNO would be a brute force way to ensure that all of the required python files are installed. INNO looks like the traditional install shield installers that Windows users are used to.

Here is the link to INNO: http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

Here is an INNO script that will install python as a python as a prereq then install your python scripts.  Obviously you will have to adjust the paths to reflect your system and you will have to download the python-x.y.z.msi file.

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "PythonTest"
#define MyAppVersion "1.5"
#define MyAppPublisher "My Company, Inc."
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "PythonTest.py"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{72A57135-5C83-4A70-83F6-965EBE7DA65C}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\engineering12\Desktop\PythonTest.py"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\engineering12\Downloads\python-2.7.8.msi"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: nocompression
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{app}\python-2.7.8.msi"""
```

Here is the script PythonTest.py:

```
import time

for i in range(100):
    print i
    time.sleep(2)
```

INNO will generate a file called setup.exe that you can distribute to your friends.  Your python scripts will be available via the start menu.

Comment: I just want to be able to distribute it so nobody has to download Python to run my programs. I am not too worried about people actually stealing my source code. I just want to easily distribute my code. @abamert

Comment: Then I know that INNO will work for you.  Basically it creates an installer exe that will install any perquisite programs that you desire.  You tell INNO which Python installers that you want to run by editing a config file.  You also use the config file to tell INNO where on the windows file system that you want to install your scripts.

If I have time today or this weekend I can show you an example.

Comment: @oiestin, I updated my answer with an INNO script that will accomplish your goal.  Remember to accept the answer by clicking on the checkbox.

Comment: Okay thank you! I will use this. :)

Comment: Note that the installers for the other python windows packages like numpy will probably be exe installers instead of .msi installers.  You will have to execute those directly instead of calling 'msiexec'.

Comment: Just a question, how do I use my own icon for the program? I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Well, I haven't tried it, but I would imagine that you would want to write a batch script (.bat) that would call your python script.  Then associate an icon with the batch script.  INNO can put the icon file wherever you need it to go.  There has to be a way to do what you want but I can only guess.  If the batch script won't work then you could write a simple exe program that can call your script.